# Should I use my two columns that uniquely identify a record as primary key?

Tags: mysql, database

I started to design a database that tracks system events by following some online tutorials, and some easy examples start by assigning auto-incrementing IDs as primary keys. I looked at my database, I don't really need IDs. Out of all my columns, the timestamp and device ID are the two columns that together identifies an unique event.

What my program does right now is to pull some events from system log in the past x minutes and insert these events to the database. However, I could be going too much into the past that the events overlap with what's already in the database. As I mentioned before, timestamp and device ID are the two fields that uniquely identify an event. My question is, should I use these two fields as my primary key and use "`Insert ignore`" from now on so I can avoid having duplicate records?

Comment: [Here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57548/how-to-set-up-multiple-fields-as-primary-key-in-mysql) is how you can do this, and I don't see anything wrong with your composite primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practise to never have your business values as table's primary key and always to use synthetic, e.g. autoincrement, values for this. You will make your life easier in the future when business requirements change :)

We are currently struggling with exactly this situation. Have a column with business values as a primary key for 2 years and now painfully introducing an autoincrement one.

Comment: How do you resolve duplicate record issue? Checking the new records (size n) against old records (size m) will have runtime O(nm)...

Comment: @return0 you still can have unique constraint on (device,timestamp) pair

Comment: ...and just to elaborate on Nikem's comment, MySQL implements unique constraints as (B-Tree) indexes—just like primary keys—so searches within it are O(log m), and the cost of checking all of the new records against it would therefore be O(n log m).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use foreign key from other table to this in the future to link some rows between two tables. It is easier with one-column primary key.
But if you don't need it now - no need to create column special for index. Table can be altered in future to add such column with autoincrement and move primary key to it.

Comment: It's quite possible to have composite foreign keys (indeed, MySQL can enforce composite foreign key constraints).

Comment: @eggyal, yes. I said only that foreign key by by one column is simplier than many-column key. You need to duplicate two, three or more columns in each table with foreign key if it is composite. And this will take much more size in table and key buffer. Special autoincrementing key column can be used to avoid this.